# PHP Composer Won't install Drush with php 5.6: phpunit/phpunit 4.8.x requires ext-dom

Tags: php, dom, drupal, composer-php, drush

so I'm working on CentOs 7 and I have been attempting to create a working Drupal Composer template (https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) that includes a site-local Drush install (http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/). For our project we need to use PHP 5.6 and Drupal 8.2.

Per the instructions above I have done the following on my clean virtualbox install of CentOS:

Installed git.

Installed php 5.6:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm 
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm 

yum install php56w php56w-opcache
```

Now I download composer and install globally:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" 
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '669656bab3166a7aff8a7506b8cb2d1c292f042046c5a994c43155c0be6190fa0355160742ab2e1c88d40d5be660b410') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" 
php composer-setup.php 

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/compose
```

I can run composer and it seems to work fine.

Now per the instructions from Drupal Composer we can create our drupal project with composer using:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction
```

The project template builds.

However, my problem is that I cannot run

```
composer require drush/drush
```

or

```
composer update
```

because I get these errors:

```
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.35 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.34 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.33 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.32 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.31 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.30 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.29 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.28 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.27 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.26 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.25 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.24 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.23 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.22 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.21 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.20 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.19 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.18 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.17 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.16 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.15 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.14 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - phpunit/phpunit 4.8.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~4.8 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.0, 4.8.1, 4.8.10, 4.8.11, 4.8.12, 4.8.13, 4.8.14, 4.8.15, 4.8.16, 4.8.17, 4.8.18, 4.8.19, 4.8.2, 4.8.20, 4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.3, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.4, 4.8.5, 4.8.6, 4.8.7, 4.8.8, 4.8.9, 4.8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
  - /etc/php.ini
  - /etc/php.d/bz2.ini
  - /etc/php.d/calendar.ini
  - /etc/php.d/ctype.ini
  - /etc/php.d/curl.ini
  - /etc/php.d/exif.ini
  - /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini
  - /etc/php.d/ftp.ini
  - /etc/php.d/gettext.ini
  - /etc/php.d/gmp.ini
  - /etc/php.d/iconv.ini
  - /etc/php.d/json.ini
  - /etc/php.d/opcache.ini
  - /etc/php.d/phar.ini
  - /etc/php.d/shmop.ini
  - /etc/php.d/simplexml.ini
  - /etc/php.d/sockets.ini
  - /etc/php.d/tokenizer.ini
  - /etc/php.d/xml.ini
  - /etc/php.d/zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Composer refuses to update.
After a few days of googling, I seem to be at a loss. I don't know what exactly I need to change in those files, and I don't see anyone having the same error with their composer downloads (and most posts seem outdated by years).

Can anyone offer any insight at all as to what I am missing here?

Thank you.

EDIT: Thanks to @Oliver I found out the issue was I needed php-xml which I installed for php5.6 using:

```
sudo yum install php56w-xml
```

Extensions can be found in the link in his comment.

Now I am figuring out what to do as I do not see drupal/core or easyrdf listed on that site. My new error is here:

```
  DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
  - drupal/core 8.0.0 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta10 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta11 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta12 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta13 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta14 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta15 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta16 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta6 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta7 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta8 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta9 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-rc1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-rc2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-rc3 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.0-rc4 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.3 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.4 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.5 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.6 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.0.x-dev requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.0 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.0-beta1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.0-beta2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.0-rc1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.10 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.3 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.4 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.5 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.6 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.7 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.8 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.9 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.1.x-dev requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.0 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.0-beta1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.0-beta2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.0-beta3 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.0-rc1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.0-rc2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.3 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.4 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.5 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.6 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.7 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.2.x-dev requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.3.0-alpha1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.3.0-beta1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.3.0-rc1 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.3.0-rc2 requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.3.x-dev requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - drupal/core 8.4.x-dev requires easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.* -> satisfiable by easyrdf/easyrdf[0.9.0, 0.9.0-rc.1, 0.9.0-rc.2, 0.9.0-rc.3, 0.9.0-rc.4, 0.9.0-rc.5, 0.9.1, 0.9.x-dev].
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.x-dev requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.0-rc.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.0-rc.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.0-rc.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.0-rc.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.0-rc.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  - Installation request for drupal/core ~8.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.0, 8.0.0-beta10, 8.0.0-beta11, 8.0.0-beta12, 8.0.0-beta13, 8.0.0-beta14, 8.0.0-beta15, 8.0.0-beta16, 8.0.0-beta6, 8.0.0-beta7, 8.0.0-beta8, 8.0.0-beta9, 8.0.0-rc1, 8.0.0-rc2, 8.0.0-rc3, 8.0.0-rc4, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.0.4, 8.0.5, 8.0.6, 8.0.x-dev, 8.1.0, 8.1.0-beta1, 8.1.0-beta2, 8.1.0-rc1, 8.1.1, 8.1.10, 8.1.2, 8.1.3, 8.1.4, 8.1.5, 8.1.6, 8.1.7, 8.1.8, 8.1.9, 8.1.x-dev, 8.2.0, 8.2.0-beta1, 8.2.0-beta2, 8.2.0-beta3, 8.2.0-rc1, 8.2.0-rc2, 8.2.1, 8.2.2, 8.2.3, 8.2.4, 8.2.5, 8.2.6, 8.2.7, 8.2.x-dev, 8.3.0-alpha1, 8.3.0-beta1, 8.3.0-rc1, 8.3.0-rc2, 8.3.x-dev, 8.4.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
  - /etc/php.ini
  - /etc/php.d/bz2.ini
  - /etc/php.d/calendar.ini
  - /etc/php.d/ctype.ini
  - /etc/php.d/curl.ini
  - /etc/php.d/dom.ini
  - /etc/php.d/exif.ini
  - /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini
  - /etc/php.d/ftp.ini
  - /etc/php.d/gettext.ini
  - /etc/php.d/gmp.ini
  - /etc/php.d/iconv.ini
  - /etc/php.d/json.ini
  - /etc/php.d/opcache.ini
  - /etc/php.d/phar.ini
  - /etc/php.d/shmop.ini
  - /etc/php.d/simplexml.ini
  - /etc/php.d/sockets.ini
  - /etc/php.d/tokenizer.ini
  - /etc/php.d/xml.ini
  - /etc/php.d/xml_wddx.ini
  - /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini
  - /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini
  - /etc/php.d/xsl.ini
  - /etc/php.d/zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Will post update when if is figured out.

FINAL EDIT: Figured out that easyrdf needs ext-mbstring and ext-pcre. ext-pcre comes installed with the common php package, so all I needed was ext-mbstring:

```
sudo yum install php56w-mbstring
```

Now when calling composer update all my dependencies were downloaded! Now I can run vender/bin/drush and the command works, confirming my local install is completed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not composer-related. You're just missing a php-extension.
I don't know what php-version you have or what Operation System is on your server. I post some examples for bash:

EDIT: NOW I HAVE FOUND YOUR VERSION:

CentOS-Example:

```
sudo yum install php56w-xml
```

You can find a list of packages for php 5.6 here: https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I am using php 5.6 and I am on CentOS. I've seen this suggested before, but when I try

   sudo yum install php-xml

I get a conflict error. Trying to find the version for 5.6 using 

   yum --showduplicates list php-xml | expand

Is not bringing up any other versions, and I can't seem to find a solution any where else online on how to find this exact extention for php 5.6.

Thanks!

Comment: I have changed my answer to your versions. php56w-xml should do it

Comment: Thank you @Oliver! 

That seems to have to have fixed the phpunit issue! Now im getting the same issue but it now says drupal/core requires easyrdf, but at least its a step forward! Looks like I will have to keep installing the correct php extensions until the dependencies are satisfied. I'll see what I can find, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I have added a link to a list of extension in my answer. Use it, if you like